# Disable PowerShell Console Coloring Without Profile Script

Tags: powershell

I have a visual impairment and cannot read the red-on-black error messages in the PowerShell console.  I've tried creating a profile script to disable it, but I get the following error.  I cannot change the default execution policy on my work machine, so I can't enable scripts.

```
. : File C:\Users\me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ . 'C:\Users\me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_ ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: Talk to your employer and/or their IT department.

Comment: as ansgar said - this is locked down on purpose by your employer, likely as a security measure, you will need to have them grant you the ability to use powershell on your own machine, you could also look at running powershell with a desktop shortcut and adding `-command "{set-foo bar}"` to the launch options, which I believe bypasses the execution policy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you already know how to change setting in PowerShell. Your issue is one of getting your workplace to recognize your impairment and offer you a solution. For help with that, you might have a look at [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a workaround, not direcly a solution to your question:

**You could try using PowerShell ISE**

You can set a **theme**, i.e. colour and layout profile, from the **Tools** > **Options** dialog box. There are plenty of options to configure for different elements of scripts and console output.

The change the colour of the background of the console section and the colour of the error messages, edit:

- Console Pane > Background
- Console Pane > Ouput Streams > Error Background (e.g. *Transparent*)
- Console Pane > Ouput Streams > Error Foreground

PowerShell ISE also supports zooming if you don't want to play with font size.

These settings will be saved between sessions without needing a profile (and as a side note: there is a different profile file for PsISE).

[powershell-ise](/questions/tagged/powershell-ise)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get around that by changing the PrivateData property of `Get-Host`.

Let's set `$window = (Get-Host).PrivateData`

If you look at the content of $window you'll get the following:

```
ErrorForegroundColor    : Red
ErrorBackgroundColor    : Black
WarningForegroundColor  : Yellow
WarningBackgroundColor  : Black
DebugForegroundColor    : Yellow
DebugBackgroundColor    : Black
VerboseForegroundColor  : Yellow
VerboseBackgroundColor  : Black
ProgressForegroundColor : Yellow
ProgressBackgroundColor : DarkCyan
```

Now, you can set any of these properties to colors that would be easy for you to see.  For instance, you could set:

`$window.ErrorForegroundColor = "blue"`

and

`$window.ErrorBackgroundColor = "yellow"`

You'd have to run this in the open powershell window that you are using, and you'd have to do this every time, in order to see the change.  In an ideal world, you'd be able to explain this to your desktop support team and they'd allow you to modify your Powershell profile and run Powershell with your profile settings in order to make the change permanent.